# Yahoo Mail POP3 settings don't work neither PHP or Yahoo Interface

Tags: php, yahoo, pop3, yahoo-mail

I tried fetching Yahoo mail programatically first with PHP, using the standards : pop.mail.yahoo.com , with SSL, on port 995. Nothing.

Then, I tried their web interface. Went to Mail Options, in Yahoo, Mail Accounts - and under my current account, I linked another existing one, also Yahoo. Keep in mind, LINKED, not created a new virtual user/mail name.

I cliked the plus sign, entered the above POP information, checked SSL, overriden the default port to 995, fetch to Inbox, leave a copy on POP server, fetch only new mail. This is what you tipically do when you want this account to fetch new mail from the linked account, right? It's like forwarding, only this account automatically fetches new mail from that Inbox to this Inbox. Right?

I'll be damned if anything worked on Yahoo. So, please enlighten me. Specifically, I'm interested more in this last option than in the PHP one. If I get this one I'll know how to work around.

Thanks alot.

P.S. : I mean why the f*&%ing sweet bone do they even offer the option in their menus if it doesn't work. Why don't they just block it with Yahoo Plus like they do on forwarding and POP'ed mail or whatever..

Comment: Your question is missing a question mark.

Comment: Sorry for that @ithcy , but I couldn't make it to sound like a question, being quite technical and about the exact mail brand.

Comment: When you tried using PHP, you should have got an error message?

Comment: This goes to SuperUser or StackOverflow?